# Seo issues placing metadata into body vs head?

Tags: seo, meta-tags

Are there any seo considerations or issues placing seo type metadata into the body of a HTML page vs the head section?

Comment: I don't know whether there are any SEO considerations, but it's simply not a valid HTML. Meta tags must be in the head.

Answer (score 1):

When it comes to placing meta data on a site it is best placed in the `<head>` section of the site. Whereas that is the first thing read when it is scanned/read by search engine bots. Here is a Google article that describes the best practices for meta data: http://support.google.com/webmasters/bin/answer.py?hl=en&answer=79812

Answer (score 0):

Its a practice to follow to place the Meta data element in the Head section.

[HTML Strucuture](http://www.w3.org/TR/html40/struct/global.html)

Regarding SEO Issues, its not written anywhere that what is advantage or not